# Why does Internet Explorer 10 and 11 not sending array via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

My question is why Internet explorer 10 and 11 is not sending anything to my controller but Internet explorer 9 sent everything fine.

For example this is the ajax function

```
function PostData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({param: Value}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //fine
        }
    });
```

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the solution, it was a add-on called Google Gears. Somewhere else I read sometimes a add-on about download manager was causing a problem and in jquery bugs site, someone was having the same problem and for my "luck" my IE had Google Gears installed, so I disabled, re-start the browser and everything works on IE11, IE10 and IE9 of course.

Hope someone find this useful one day.

Comment: Unrelated, but there are several ajax options that you can omit in this case: `async`, `cache`, `traditional`

Comment: Yes I know but I added them to ensure everything works fine but nothing works.

Comment: Are you using a recent-ish version of jquery?

Comment: Yes, I tried with 2.1.0, with 1.10, with 1.11 and the ones that are "stable"

Comment: Next step is press F12 and go to network, and try to send the request again. Or, better yet, install fiddler and inspect the request there.

Comment: I tried with F12 and do some test, with IE9 the "request body" was the json string I put in my question, but on IE 10 and 11 was empty. And about fiddler I dont have privileges on this computer, I will try to install it...

Comment: was the json string anywhere else in the request?

Comment: No it wasn't. It's a simple javascript object created on the page. Then I start "pushing" the array with the elements you saw (Cart.Credits.push(elements)). And that's all. It simple the usage. And about fiddler I couldn't install it because I don't have admin privileges.

Comment: Just for the sake of thorough testing, perform the ajax request without jquery to confirm that it does work that way.

Comment: Well this could take a while, let me do some research about plain javascript ajax and not jquery.

Comment: Well I copied and existing script of ajax with javascript (without jquery) and it's the same. I tested with Firefox and works fine, I test it with IE9 and works, but on IE 10 and IE11 still null.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DpK3jPQr

Comment: If you're getting the same result without using jquery, i'm not sure what to look at. i haven't encountered this issue before in my own environment. Can you test it on another computer?

Comment: Thanks for the code, I manage to find it in stackoverflow the script. And about the ajax stuff, well something about the new document mode on IE 10 and 11 could be the responsible and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You do have standards chosen and not compatibility, right?

Comment: Yes standard. I'm using "compatibily" as a last resource with the **<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">** and that way it's working but without it it's not working. And additional details on F12 the content-length is 16, on Firefox and IE. But IE the request body is empty.

Comment: According to the solution given in the original post, I confirm this issue is caused by Google Gears Plugin for IE > 10. Is there a way to fix this without disabling this plugin ? I'm working on a public project, and I really can't ask my clients to disable a plugin on their browser to make the site working correctly.